# type of column conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
   RMS_Code, Property, Value
FROM
    (SELECT 
         RMS_Code, 
         ITEM_CODE= CONVERT(VARCHAR(320),ITEM_CODE),
         ITEM_DESC= CONVERT(VARCHAR(320),ITEM_DESC),
         [SECOND_DESCRIPTION] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(320),   [SECOND_DESCRIPTION]), 
         [IBC] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(320), [IBC]),
         [ITEM_GROUP] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(320), [ITEM_GROUP]), 
         [Main_Item] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(320),[Main_Item]),
         AGGREGATE_CODE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(320),AGGREGATE_CODE),
         ITEM_TYPE = convert(varchar(320),ITEM_TYPE)
     FROM 
         [dbo].[RMS_Master_11]) AS t
UNPIVOT
(
  Value FOR Property IN ( ITEM_CODE,ITEM_DESC,
    [SECOND_DESCRIPTION], 
    [IBC],ITEM_GROUP, Main_Item,AGGREGATE_CODE,ITEM_TYPE
    )
) AS up;
```

The error message:

> Msg 8167, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
>   The type of column "ITEM_TYPE" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: CAST ITEM_TYPE to be the same data types as the other columns in your unpivot list.

Comment: What about `RMS_Code` ??? is it also VARCHAR(320) ??

Comment: RMS_Code is just a column name and it is nvarchar(50)

Comment: so what could be  the modification on the above scirpt